# Foreach (class variable in currentScope) in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, scope

Is it possible in C# to declare various instances of a class inside a scope and then work on them with a `foreach` loop?

Example:

```
void generateInstances()
{
    myClass element1 = new myClass();
    myClass element2 = new myClass();
    myClass element3 = new myClass();

    foreach (myClass e in currentScope)
    {
        e.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add them to some kind of collection

Comment: let's say I have like hundreds of elements.
I wanted to add them to a list like this:
`foreach (myClass e in scope){
myList.Add(e)
}`

Comment: You need to add to your class a global of type `List<myClass>` and whenever you create an instance add it to your list. At this point you could use the list for your loops.

Comment: It is possible .. but the `architecture` to accomplish is complex..

Comment: @Moumit I've already solved the problem the classical way, but I'm curious :)

Comment: @TizianoCoroneo .. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **it's possible**.

Here below is the `code architecture` ..

```
public class DemoClass
{
    //static List<DemoClass> _currentList = null;
    static List<DemoClass> _currentList = new List<DemoClass>();
    static bool _isScopeStarted = false;

    public DemoClass()
    {
        if (_isScopeStarted)
        {
            _currentList.Add(this);
        }
    }

    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<DemoClass> ScopeObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentList;
        }
    }

    public int Sum()
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void StartScope()
    { 
        //_currentList = new List<DemoClass>();            
        _isScopeStarted = true;
    }

    public static void EndScope()
    {
        //_currentList = null;
        _isScopeStarted = false;
        _currentList = new List<DemoClass>();
    }
```

Now the `unit testing` part

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //When no scope defined
        DemoClass alone1 = new DemoClass();
        DemoClass alone2 = new DemoClass();
        Console.WriteLine(DemoClass.ScopeObjects.Count());

        //When scope is defined
        DemoClass.StartScope();

        DemoClass demo1 = new DemoClass { a = 10, b = 20 };
        DemoClass demo2 = new DemoClass { a = 11, b = 22 };
        Console.WriteLine(DemoClass.ScopeObjects.Count());

        //Here is your for each
        foreach (var item in DemoClass.ScopeObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Sum());
        }

        DemoClass.EndScope();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

`@Tiziano` check whether is it fit of your `curiosity` satisfied

Comment: Wonderful solution @Moumit :)

Answer (score 3):

Like everybody said, you must use collections to do this, for example:

```
void generateInstaces()
{    
    myClass element1 = new myClass();
    myClass element2 = new myClass();
    myClass element3 = new myClass();

    var myCollection = new List<myClass>{ element1, element2, element3 };

    foreach (myClass e in myCollection)
    {
        e.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or you could receive the collection from method's parameter

```
void generateInstaces(IList<myClass> myCollection)
{
    foreach (myClass e in myCollection)
         e.doSomething();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

You would have to add the objects to a collection first, and then make a foreach loop over the collection.

Comment: this is so sad :( I'll just begin to write this ginormous list of instances. thank you for your help

Comment: @killpinguon Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can have many instances like this in a list:

```
void generateInstaces()
{
    List<myClass> elements = new List<myClass>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
        elements.Add(new myClass());

    foreach (myClass e in elements)
    {
        e.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Based on your comment, you could do:

```
void generateInstaces()
{
    List<myClass> elements = new List<myClass>();

    elements.Add(new myClass(1, "99a"));
    elements.Add(new myClass(17, "hta"));
    elements.Add(new myClass(9, "fff"));

    foreach (myClass e in elements)
    {
        e.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: each instance has different arguments in the initializer... :(

Comment: You can add each element individually. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

If all the instances are of same class i.e. "myClass", then u can create a list of that class type.

Then add all the instances to this list like:

```
void generateInstaces()
{
   List<myClass> myClassList = new List<myClass>();

   myClass element1 = new myClass();
   myClass element2 = new myClass();
   myClass element3 = new myClass();

   myClassList.add(element1);
   myClassList.add(element2);
   myClassList.add(element3);

   foreach (myClass mc in myClassList)
   {
       mc.doSomething();
   }
}
```

This is possible if all the instances are of same class i.e."myClass".

If the instances are of diffrent classes,Then you need to create a list of object type like below:

```
void generateInstaces()
{
   List<object> myClassList = new List<object>();

   FirstClass element1 = new FirstClass();
   SecondClass element2 = new SecondClass();
   ThirdClass element3 = new ThirdClass();

   myClassList.add(element1);
   myClassList.add(element2);
   myClassList.add(element3);

   foreach (object mc in myClassList)
   {
       if(mc.GetType() == "FirstClass")
       {
           //Do something
       }
       else if(mc.GetType() == "SecondClass")
       {
           //Do something
       }
       else if(mc.GetType() == "ThirdClass")
       {
           //Do something
       }
   }
}
```